# SVN Checkout in Perl script failing, URL not found?

Tags: perl, svn

I am writing a simple Perl script that is attempting to automate checking in files via SVN. I am not using any given SVN clients within Perl and for the sake of simplicity am just using command line arguments.

Whenever I run the svn checkout command seen below, I am getting this error:

`sh[2]: svn+ssh://my/repo/url/project/trunk: not found.`

Here is the command and the variable declarations.

```
$svn_root = "svn+ssh://my/repo/url/project/trunk";
$user = `whoami`;
`svn checkout -q --username $user $svn_root workingCopyName`;
```

I should note that I am connecting to the repository via SSH and have edited my config file (and included -q just in case). I will also note that running this command outside of the script works perfectly fine, for the same exact URL, and without the -q argument.

Thanks for your help. Please let me know if I need to clear anything up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the error is coming from the shell, not `svn`.

You are executing

```
svn checkout -q --username user
svn+ssh://my/repo/url/project/trunk workingCopyName
```

when you mean to execute

```
svn checkout -q --username user svn+ssh://my/repo/url/project/trunk workingCopyName
```

because `$user` contains a newline. Replace

```
my $user = `whoami`;
```

with

```
chomp( my $user = `whoami` );
```

Comment: Thank you. I was printing my variables to confirm they were right but lazily skipped user as I couldn't have imagined it being the problem. Much appreciated.

Comment: Could have printed out the command! `my $cmd = qq\`...\`; print("cmd=<$cmd>\n"); \`$cmd\`;`